# Codeigniter Session Library - HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-hmvc

I ran into a problem, while coding around in CI 3.0.3 and latest [HMVC Extension](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc). I'm autoloading some libraries, helpers and much more. The Session library too. Now i have a few controllers all working fine, except one.

In that controller i use this code:

```
modules::run($module->module . '/' . $module->controller . '/' . $module->method, unserialize($block->configuration));
```

While using this static function i got the error:

```
Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php
```

The log says that the Session class is initialized.

```
INFO - 2015-12-01 09:41:40 --> Session: Class initialized using 'database' driver.
```

Any ideas why i got this error?

EDIT: -----------------------------------------------------------------------

To prevent stupid answers as below ...

> In CI we can’t call more than 1 controller per request. Therefore, to achieve HMVC, we have to simulate controllers. It can be done with libraries, or with this “Modular Extensions HMVC” contribution.
>
> The differences between using a library and a “Modular HMVC” HMVC class is: 1. No need to get and use the CI instance within an HMVC class 2. HMVC classes are stored in a modules directory as opposed to the libraries directory.

EDIT 2: ---------------------------------------------------------------------

For further questions:

- Yes, the Session Library is the problem
- Yes, only in combination with this HMVC Plugin
- Yes, only if you use the static method `modules::run();`
- No, i need this method for simulating a controller in a controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.

If you want to load a controller in a controller use:

```
Modules::load();
```

or outsource the `Modules::run();` into a view that is loaded by the main controller.

Simple.